# Emulate c cast operation of float to int in python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert for example:
6.09677e-321 -> 1234
in c you can do something like: `printf("%lld", 6.09677e-321)`
Any ideas of how to get that casting into python?

I've tried with ctypes, `d=c_float(6.09677e-321);cast(f, c_longlong)` but didn't get much out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python `int` and `float` types are not like primitive C numeric types. They are full-fledged objects. Python objects don't really have "casts" in that sense. However, you can do this using `ctypes`, which essentially provides object-oriented wrappers over primitive C types. It will be a little convoluted though:

```
import ctypes

py_float = 6.097e-321

cf = ctypes.c_double(py_float)
lp = ctypes.cast(ctypes.pointer(cf), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64))

py_int = lp.contents.value
print(py_int) # 1234
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [struct module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) for this:

```
>>> import struct
# treat the value as a double
>>> packed = struct.pack("d", 6.097e-321)
>>> packed
'\xd2\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
# ...but unpack it as a long int
>>> unpacked = struct.unpack("l", packed)
>>> unpacked[0]
1234
```